# app delegate method is not calling after authentication from browser in ios using google plus sdk

Tags: google-plus-one

I have integrated google plus in my iphone application. When I sign-in by button, it redirects for the authentication on the safari browser.when i successfully login and accept it come back to the application that work fine when app coming back it should call the delegate method

```
- (BOOL)application: (UIApplication *)application 
openURL: (NSURL *)url 
sourceApplication: (NSString *)sourceApplication 
annotation: (id)annotation
{
    return [GPPURLHandler handleURL:url sourceApplication:sourceApplication annotation:annotation];
}
```

but my application is not calling this method.